# file read error

Tags: c

I am reading a byte stream from a txt file. Ex: 01000101 = 4 bytes.

```
FILE *file;
 char buffer_msg[100] = { '0' };
 char line[100] = { '0' };

file = fopen("name.txt",'r');

if(file!=NULL)
      {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)!=NULL)
           {
                     strcpy( buffer_msg, line);
           }
       }
```

then i am passing this buffer_msg to a function. Now when i am debugging in eclipse, and chk the memory of buffer_msg it reads the 4 byte data as 3031 3030 3031 3031. My guess is it is reading my data 0001 0000 0001 0001 in that format. Can any body tell what is going on? I guess the text file ends with \r\n. Am i reading the file wrong?

Comment: Are you aware of ASCII encoding? "0" = 30h, "1" = 31h

Comment: The mode string on [fopen](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html) should be a string i.e. "r" rather than 'r'.

Comment: I'm thinking that if you want to initialize your char buffers at all, you want the first character to be '\0' (NUL) not '0' (the digit zero). Not a problem in the code above, but will cause confusion the next time you apply this pattern.

Comment: I assume your input file is binary? Note the 2nd arg to fopen() is a char* not a char. You could try a mode of "rb", but I think that is obsolete on most platforms these days...

Comment: it is not binary, but hex format. and yes i have used "r". I made a mistake while typing here.

Comment: @Deepka - whenever possible, please cut and paste your code from your dev environment to your question. Retyping invariably introduces errors as you've seen.

Comment: @Bob - Sure. Will do from next time. Thank you all for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strcpy`, you need something like this:

```
void parse(char *buffer, char *line) {
  while (*line) {
     *buffer++ = (hex2char(line[0]) << 4) + hex2char(line[1]);
     line += 2;
  }
}
```

This will take two bytes from `line`, convert the hexadecimal digits to an integer and store it into one byte of `buffer`.

This will work for hex2char:

```
char hex2char(char digit) {
  if (digit >= '0' && digit <= '9') {
    return digit - '0';
  } else if (digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'F') {
    return digit - 'A' + 10;
  } else if (digit >= 'a' && digit <= 'f') {
    return digit - 'a' + 10;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise answer.